# "error: A value of type 'double' can't be assigned to a variable of type 'int' " when performing sum of digits in Flutter

Tags: flutter, dart

I tried to do sum of digits with int data type but it keeps throwing me an error as mentioned above. I need my answer without decimals so I do not want to use 'double' data type. Kindly review and help.
**I have mentioned the error point as comments in this program below.**

```
while (sum > 0) {
m = sum % 10;
total = total + m;
sum = sum / 10; //Error is pointed here
}
print(total);
Navigator.of(context).push(MaterialPageRoute(
builder: (context) => screen2(value: total),
));
},
child: Text('Submit'),
```

Comment: Whats the variable type for `sum` `total` and `m`?

Comment: They are all 'int' type

Comment: you can do `sum = sum ~/ 10;`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is because `sum/10` is a double even if the variable `sum` is an int. If you don't care about the fractional part after dividing sum with 10, you can take the integer part like this..

```
sum = (sum / 10).floor();
```